# MongoConnection error with deno and mongo@v0.31.1

Tags: mongodb, deno

I can not connect to mongo atlas from my deno app. it was working somehow- now it doesn`t.
I also checked my network access options.

here`s my code:

```
import { dotEnvConfig, MongoClient } from "../deps.ts";
const configData = await dotEnvConfig();

const { MONGO_USER_NAME, MONGO_USER_PASSWORD, MONGO_HOSTNAME, MONGO_PORT } =
  configData;



const client = new MongoClient();

// Connecting to a Mongo Atlas Database
await client.connect({
  db: "dip",
  tls: true,
  servers: [
    {
      host: MONGO_HOSTNAME,
      port: 27017,
    },
  ],
  credential: {
    username: MONGO_USER_NAME,
    password: MONGO_USER_PASSWORD,
    db: "dip",
    mechanism: "SCRAM-SHA-1",
  },
});

const db = client.database("dip");

export default db;
```

here`s my error:

error: Uncaught (in promise) Error: MongoError: "Connection failed: Could not find a master node"
throw new MongoDriverError(`Connection failed: ${e.message || e}`);
^
at MongoClient.connect (https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.31.1/src/client.ts:46:13)
at async file:///E:/webstuff/deno/db/mongodb.ts:12:1

Answer (score 0):

Check in mongo atlas if your primary cluster wasn't change. That's what happened to me.